# Compile Qt Installer Framework static

Tags: c++, qt

I compiled static qt according to instructions in qt istaller.
I'm trying to assemble qt installer. On the binarycreator module, linker issues errors:

```
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__OpenThemeData@8 referenced in function "public: class QColor __thiscall QVistaHelper::basicWindowFrameColor(void)" (?basicWindowFrameColor@QVistaHelper@@QAE?AVQColor@@XZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__OpenThemeData@8
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__OpenThemeData@8
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DrawThemeBackground@24 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QVistaBackButton::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QVistaBackButton@@UAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeColor@20 referenced in function "public: class QColor __thiscall QVistaHelper::basicWindowFrameColor(void)" (?basicWindowFrameColor@QVistaHelper@@QAE?AVQColor@@XZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeColor@20
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeColor@20
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeSysFont@12 referenced in function "struct tagLOGFONTW __cdecl getCaptionLogFont(void *)" (?getCaptionLogFont@@YA?AUtagLOGFONTW@@PAX@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsThemeActive@0 referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl QVistaHelper::drawBlackRect(class QRect const &,struct HDC__ *)" (?drawBlackRect@QVistaHelper@@CA_NABVQRect@@PAUHDC__@@@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsThemeActive@0
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetWindowThemeAttribute@16 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QVistaHelper::setTitleBarIconAndCaptionVisible(bool)" (?setTitleBarIconAndCaptionVisible@QVistaHelper@@QAEX_N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwizard_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DrawThemeTextEx@36 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall QVistaHelper::drawTitleText(class QPainter *,class QString const &,class QRect const &,struct HDC__ *)" (?drawTitleText@QVistaHelper@@AAE_NPAVQPainter@@ABVQString@@ABVQRect@@PAUHDC__@@@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CloseThemeData@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::cleanupHandleMap(void)" (?cleanupHandleMap@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAEXXZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DrawThemeBackgroundEx@24 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundDirectly(struct HDC__ *,class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundDirectly@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NPAUHDC__@@AAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeBackgroundRegion@24 referenced in function "public: struct HRGN__ * __thiscall XPThemeData::mask(class QWidget *)" (?mask@XPThemeData@@QAEPAUHRGN__@@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemePartSize@28 referenced in function "public: class QSizeF __thiscall XPThemeData::size(void)" (?size@XPThemeData@@QAE?AVQSizeF@@XZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemePartSize@28
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent@12 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer(class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NAAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeBool@20 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer(class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NAAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeInt@20 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer(class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NAAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeInt@20
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeEnumValue@20 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer(class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NAAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeEnumValue@20
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeMargins@28 referenced in function "public: class QMarginsF __thiscall XPThemeData::margins(class QRect const &,int)" (?margins@XPThemeData@@QAE?AVQMarginsF@@ABVQRect@@H@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeMargins@28
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemePropertyOrigin@20 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer(class XPThemeData &,double)" (?drawBackgroundThruNativeBuffer@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE_NAAVXPThemeData@@N@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemePropertyOrigin@20
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetWindowTheme@12 referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl QWindowsXPStylePrivate::initVistaTreeViewTheming(void)" (?initVistaTreeViewTheming@QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@CA_NXZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsAppThemed@0 referenced in function "public: __thiscall QWindowsXPStylePrivate::QWindowsXPStylePrivate(void)" (??0QWindowsXPStylePrivate@@QAE@XZ)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsxpstyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetCurrentThemeName@24 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QWindowsXPStyle::drawPrimitive(enum QStyle::PrimitiveElement,class QStyleOption const *,class QPainter *,class QWidget const *)const " (?drawPrimitive@QWindowsXPStyle@@UBEXW4PrimitiveElement@QStyle@@PBVQStyleOption@@PAVQPainter@@PBVQWidget@@@Z)
Qt5Widgets.lib(qwindowsvistastyle.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetThemeTransitionDuration@24 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QWindowsVistaStyle::drawControl(enum QStyle::ControlElement,class QStyleOption const *,class QPainter *,class QWidget const *)const " (?drawControl@QWindowsVistaStyle@@UBEXW4ControlElement@QStyle@@PBVQStyleOption@@PAVQPainter@@PBVQWidget@@@Z)
```

Compilation flags qt:

```
configure -prefix "C:\Qt\static" -release -static -static-runtime -opensource -confirm-license  -accessibility -no-opengl -no-icu -no-sql-sqlite -no-qml-debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtserialport -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtxmlpatterns -skip qt3d
```

Qt version 5.8.0(qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.zip) for win32-msvc2013.

Comment: Qt 5.8 is FULL of compilation problems. Start with Qt 5.7, and then if it works, move to 5.8.

Comment: Qt 5.7 build is also broken, and [it won't be fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59716).

Comment: I tried Qt 5.4.2 and get only one error:

    Qt5Qml.lib(qqmldebugserver.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall QTcpServerConnection::QTcpServerConnection(void)" (??0QTcpServerConnection@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall QQmlDebugServerThread::run(void)" (?run@QQmlDebugServerThread@@UAEXXZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `UxTheme.lib` is not found by linker or missing in build config.

Try to add `LIBS += -LPath_To_UxTheme -lUxTheme`.

Comment: I did not find where this library is. In the qt binaries there are only *.h files with a similar name

Comment: It's a part of WinSDK, usually `LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case version 5.5.1 helped. Details in [solution](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57888/solved-qt5-5-static-build-failed-qqmldebugserverthread-run-error-undefined-reference-to-qtcpserverconnection-qtcpserverconnection/9)
Compiled with:

```
configure -prefix "C:\Qt\static" -platform win32-msvc2013 -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -no-sql-sqlite -no-qml-debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtserialport -skip qtquick1 -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtxmlpatterns -skip qt3d -opengl desktop -no-angle  -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -no-openssl -make libs -make tools
```